# Loading an html document to JTextPane is making my editor to behave very badly in paste

Tags: java, swing, paste, jtextpane

I am making editor. I am using following code to add html document from a path to texteditor.

```
try {       
    filename="filepath";
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int numRead=0;
    while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
        String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
        fileData.append(readData);
        buf = new char[1024];
    }
    reader.close();
    result = fileData.toString();
    jtextpane.setContentType("text/html");
    jtextpane.setText(result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    jtextpane.setText(".,1..."+ex.toString());
}
```

Till the time when i m not using this file to load at first time my editor is working fine. But after adding this code my paste button is not working properly.It is pasting in new line. when i am removing *"**SETCONTENTTYPE**"* in that scenario the paste is working well.but i can't remove it.I have to load html file into editor. Please help.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: So are you saying that paste stops working whenever this code is present or after this code runs?

Comment: How does your paste button work? What's the code?

Comment: not paste works but it will paste data in new line.

Comment: Here's my code of paste : button.addActionListener(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());

Answer (score 1):

If you want "open" the html document in your text editor, you should use a JEditorPane combined (if it's necessary) which a JScrollPane. Here's an example code (It needs try/catch blocks):

```
private void visualiserLog() {
    JEditorPane docEP = new JEditorPane();
    docEP.setEditable(true);
    File f = new File(/path/to/file.html);
    java.net.URL fileURL = null;
    try {
        fileURL = f.toURI().toURL(); // Transform path into URL
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        docEP.setPage(fileURL); // Load the file to the editor
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Initialize scroll pane (if you need it)
    JScrollPane docSP = new JScrollPane(docEP, 
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    docSP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,700));

    // Set up a frame to layout the editor panel
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HTML File");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setBounds(0,0,800,700);
    // If you don't use ScrollPane, you must swap docSP for docEP
    frame.getContentPane().add(docSP,BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I think that can works properly to set the file into the editor. After that you should put the copy function and the necessary listeners.

Regards!